# When generating arrays from arrays using ".push", how can I better "randomize" my results and control for duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on this practice problem to learn JavaScript. I hope to later be able to do the same in Python and Java. But for now, I am trying to create a list of 30 unique lunches.

> Tanya is the manager of her school system’s cafeterias.  Every month she needs to come up with school lunches for the next month.  The school lunches should have a variety of different mains, sides, and desserts.
>
> Write Tanya a program that will put together her lunches for her.
> Come up with a list of mains, sides, and desserts
> Be able to generate a list of meals.
> The meals should be unique.

I'm trying to generate 30 combinations of arrays that consist of "main course", "sides", and "desserts", but without duplicate entries.

I have 5 mains, 5 sides, and 5 desserts, and the code I wrote spits out 125 different meals, although there is a lot of repetition. What I want is to be able to better organize this into 30 day blocks, like for November, December, etc. I want to write a program that will allow the fictitious client to input new mains,sides, or desserts, but I guess that would require some front-end HTML and Jquery?

```
const MEAL_COUNT = 30;

const mains=["Chicken sandwich ", "Lasagna ", "Pizza ", "Fried Beefcake ", "Soylent Shake "];
const sides=["Fries ", "Apple slices ", "Tater Tots ", "Sad Salad ", "Hard-boiled egg "];
const desserts=["Rice Pudding ", "Gluten-free cookie ", "Cheesecake Delux ", "Sundae ", "Graham Crackers "];

const meals = [];

const mealIdentifiers = [];

while (meals.length < MEAL_COUNT) {

    let mainId = Math.floor(Math.random() * mains.length);
    let sideId = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length);
    let dessertId= Math.floor(Math.random() * desserts.length);

    let mealId = `${mainId}${sideId}${dessertId}`;

if (mealId.includes(id)) {
        continue;
}

meals.push({
    main: mains[mainId],
    side: sides[sideId],
    dessert: desserts[dessertId]
  });
}

console.log(meals);
```

EDIT: I got this code to work by removing the "id" in `if (mealId.includes())`

UPDATE2: I've got this to display in a pretty way in HTML! Just wanted to share! [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crvwx2ap)

Comment: If you want it to be random, you could just shuffle the list afterwards couldn't your?

Comment: It feels like you are asking a couple of questions at the same time and it's not clear what is it exactly you want to be answered?
Is it making your code more random? cleaner? or do you want tips on UI?
Try to be more explicit and maybe split your questiosn

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. Yes, let's just say I want to shuffle the list afterwards, and divide it into sections of 30. It looks like Pomax provided me with some direction on this, so I will look over that for now.

Comment: You could either use a set. Or, use an object which is more or less like a hashmap in that context. The values you have already seen you set as key in the object with a value e.g. true. Now whenever you want to stick something in the array, you first check if this key returns true on your object, if so, you have a dupe. I think the object is much more efficient than let say, array.includes or array.indexOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterating over each array, iterate "until you have 30 meals", using `Math.random()` to get elements from your mains, sides, and desserts at each iteration, and then checking "did I already create this combination before?". If you did, ignore it and retry, and if you didn't, add it to your list of meals:

```
const MEAL_COUNT = 30;

const mains = [...];
const sides = [...];
const desserts = [...];

// we start with an empty meal list.
const meals = [];

// and meal compositions are unique, so we need a way to track them.
const mealIdentifiers = [];

// start inventing meals!
while (meals.length < MEAL_COUNT) {

  // Get three random element ids, rounded down
  let mainId = Math.floor(Math.random() * mains.length);
  let sideId = Math.floor(Math.random() * mains.length);
  let puddId = Math.floor(Math.random() * mains.length);

  // form the unique identifier for this meal. In this case
  // we simply string-combine the ids, but that WON'T WORK
  // for lists that are more than 9 elements long (and you
  // should be able to explain why).
  let mealId = `${mainId}${sideId}${puddId}`;

  // have we seen this unique meal already?
  if (mealIdentifiers.includes(mealId)) {
    // we have. Continue to the next iteration.
    continue;
  }

  // if we get here, we haven't, so add it to the list.

  meals.push({
    main: mains[mainId],
    side: sides[sideId],
    dessert: desserts[puddId]
  });

  mealIdentifiers.push(mealId);
}
```

Your `meals` array now contains 30 meals, each one a convenient object with a `.main`, `.side`, and `.dessert` property that you can reference in whatever code you have to actually present this information to a user.

Comment: Wow, this is a great and highly detailed answer! I will try to incorporate a few elements from your examples. I just hope i can actually learn this stuff, rather than tossing together other peoples' code!

Comment: Hmm I'm just doing this in console and not getting any feedback when I try to view a result using "console.log(meals)". Can you tell me why I might be getting no results? Editing initial post

Comment: I just wanted to say I got a positive result once I removed the "id" from if (mealId.includes()) {
  continue;
} because for some reason it was holding it up

Comment: seems like you are missing a `mealIdentifiers.push(mealId)`

Comment: Thank you Brandon!